# SQL error on Database Import, while setting up staging site

Tags: database, import, magento2.4, sql

I have been trying to import a database to clone a production site that is working and I am receiving this error when trying to import the database.

```
Error
Static analysis:

2 errors were found during analysis.

Unrecognized statement type. (near "DEFINER" at position 27)
Unrecognized statement type. (near "END" at position 353)
SQL query:

/* 50003 CREATE*/ /*!50017 DEFINER=`upper_mg2`@`localhost`*/ /*!50003 TRIGGER trg_catalog_category_entity_after_insert AFTER INSERT ON catalog_category_entity FOR EACH ROW BEGIN INSERT IGNORE INTO `catalog_category_product_cl` (`entity_id`) VALUES (NEW.`entity_id`); INSERT IGNORE INTO `catalog_category_flat_cl` (`entity_id`) VALUES (NEW.`entity_id`); END */

MySQL said:Documentation

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DEFINER=`upper_mg2`@`localhost`*/ /*!50003 TRIGGER trg_catalog_category_entity_a' at line 1
```

Any help on how to fix, would be much appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: How you export that database which you are currently try to import?

Comment: DEFINER is not a universally supported feature. This might be a better question for https://dba.stackexchange.com/, but there is some info here based on another environment where DEFINER is an issue https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/definer-error-mysqldump/